# Contact of a curve in the origin

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $G:[0,1]\to [0,\infty)$ is an $C^2$ function satisfying $$at^{\Gamma_2}\leq G(t)\leq at^{\Gamma_1},\ \forall\ t\in[0,1]$$

where $a>0$ and $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2>1$ are constansts with $\Gamma_1\leq\Gamma_2$. Assume also that $G$ is strictly convex.  Define $A_1$ and $A_2$ by:

$A_1=\{s\in [\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2]:\ c_st^s\leq G(t)\ \mbox{for some $c_s>0$, $t\in [0,\delta_s]$ and}\ \forall c'_s>0,\ G(t)\ \mbox{cannot be majorated by $c'_st^s$ for any interval $[0,\delta'_s]$} \}$

$A_2=\{s\in [\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2]:\ G(t)\leq d_st^s\ \mbox{for some $d_s>0$ and $t\in [0,\epsilon_s]$ and}\ \forall d'_s>0,\ G(t)\ \mbox{cannot be minorated by $d'_st^s$ for any interval $[0,\epsilon'_s]$} \}$

Define $k_1$ and $k_2$ by $k_1=\inf A_1$ and $k_2=\sup A_2$.

Suppose that $\Gamma_2\in A_1$ and $\Gamma_1\in A_2$.

My question is:

a) Can we prove that the infimum and the maximum is attained?

b) Is $k_1=k_2$ ?

Update 1: I have changed a little bit the sets $A_1$ and $A_2$. Now we have that for every $q>k_1$, $q\notin A_2$, so $k_1\geq k_2$.

Thanks

Comment: I would suspect that $k_1=k_2 = 2$ and that, in general, the bound is not attained.

Comment: @copper.hat Do you have some idea to give me, because I am really stuck on this problem.

Comment: I mean that the infimum is attained by some $s\in [\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2]$. Do you agree with me that $k_1=k_2$?

Comment: Well, since $G$ is convex and $C^2$, it can be written as $G(t) = G(0) + t G'(0) + \frac{1}{2}t^2 G''(\xi)$ for some $\xi \in (0,t)$.

Comment: I don't have time right now, I will look at it again later. In the last comment, since $G$ is $C^2$ you can replace the last term by $\frac{1}{2}t^2 G''(0)+ o(t^2)$.

Comment: @copper.hat also we have that $G(0)=G'(0)=0$.

Comment: I spent some time on this but am presently stumped.

Comment: @copper.hat, haha join to the club. Anyway, take a look in question linked to this one, maybe it could help.

Comment: How do you define the $A_k$?

Comment: $A_1$ is the set of the infimum and $A_2$ is the set of the maximum. @copper.hat

Comment: @copper.hat , in my calculations $A_1=(k_1,\Gamma_2]$ or $A_1=[k_1,\Gamma_2]$ and $A_2=[\Gamma_1,k_2)$ $or A_2=[\Gamma_1,k_2]$. Do you think this is right?

Comment: @copper.hat, also this example here given by $Julian is interesting: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370715/gt-leq-cta-implies-gt-leq-c-epsilon-ta-epsilon/370768?noredirect=1#comment795871_370768

Comment: @copper.hat, I think that the last example is a counter example for what I want.

Comment: I don't how you are defining $A_1,A_2$.

Comment: @copper.hat, I have edited the question, take a look.

Comment: I'll have a look later, I need to wrap my head around the new definition.

Comment: Ok @copper.hat, take your time and thanks for your help again.

Comment: Why did you add the 'cannot be m{aj,in}orated by' part to the $A_k$ definitions? I am having a hard part wrapping my head around this part.

Comment: @copper.hat Because in this way, I have wrote the set $[\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2]=A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3$, where $A_3$ is the set of $s\in [\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2]$, such that $c_s t^s\leq G(t)\leq d_s t^s$ for some $c_s,d_s>0$ and $t$ small.

Comment: From what I can tell, these definitions mean that for a function like $f(x) = x^2$, then $A_1 = A_2 = \emptyset$.

Comment: @copper.hat, I think not. In your case, we can take for example $\Gamma_1=\frac{3}{2}$ and $\Gamma_2=\frac{5}{2}$. Then $A_1=[\Gamma_1,2)$, $A_2=(2,\gamma_2]$ and $A_3=\{2\}$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I need more caffeine.

Comment: @copper.hat, This problem is interesting, maybe we could be able to characterize the functions for which $A_3\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: @copper.hat, suppose that $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\log (G(t))}{\log (t)}=k$. Can we deduce that there exist positive constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $$c_1 t^k\leq G(t)\leq c_2 t^k$$ for $t$ small?

Comment: I think if $k>0$, then for all $\epsilon \in (0,k)$  and $t>0$ sufficiently small, the above just implies $t^{k-\epsilon} > G(t) > t^{k+\epsilon}$.