# $G(t)\leq ct^A$ implies $G(t)\leq c_\epsilon t^{A+\epsilon}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $G:[0,1]\to [0,\infty]$ is a strictly convex function with $G(0)=0$ and $G\in C^2$. Suppose also that for some $A>1$, whenever $c>0$, we have that $$G(t)\leq  ct^A$$

in some interval $[0,s_c]$, where $s_c$ is a value depending on $c$. Can we find some $\epsilon>0$ and some $c_\epsilon>0$ such that $$G(t)\leq c_\epsilon t^{A+\epsilon}$$

in some interval $[0,s_{c_\epsilon}]$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider for example
$$
G(t)=\frac{t^p}{1+\log(1/t)},\quad p\ge2.
$$
$G$ is $C^2$ and strictly convex on $[\,0,1\,]$. Take $A=p$. Given $c>0$,
$$
G(t)\le c\,t^A,\quad 0\le t\le e^{1-1/c}.
$$
However for any $\epsilon>0$ and $s>0$
$$
\sup_{0\le t\le s}\frac{G(t)}{t^{A+\epsilon}}=\sup_{0\le t\le s}\frac{1}{(1+\log(1/t))t^{\epsilon}}=\infty.
$$

Comment: I am confused @Julian. Let $p=2$ and $f(t)=G(t)-2t^{2+.001}$. Then $f(0)=0$ and $f'(t)\leq 0$ near the origin. Are my calculations wrong?

Comment: For any $p\ge2$ and $C>0$: $G(t)-C\,t^{p+\epsilon}=t^p(((1+\log(1/t))^{-1}-C\,t^\epsilon)$. As $t\to0^+$, both terms inside the parenthesis converge to $0$,but $t^\epsilon$ much faster than $((1+\log(1/t))^{-1}$, since $\lim_{t\to0^+}t^\epsilon(1+\log(1/t))=0$. This means that for any $\delta>0$ there exists $T_\delta>0$ such that $t^\epsilon(1+\log(1/t))\le\delta$ on $[0,T_\delta]$, that is $((1+\log(1/t))^{-1}\ge t^\epsilon/\delta$. What happens is that $T_\delta$ is extremely small.

Comment: Ok thank you @julian.